# Sort scandir() by creation time

Tags: c, posix

In my program I am displaying a list of files. Right now I am using scandir with the built in alphasort function, however I would like to sort based upon creation date. I wrote my own comparission function but no matter how much I test it does not work. The items appear in a seemingly random order. Some may be in order, but then the oldest file might show up in the middle. For instance, say I have the following output from ls

```
Nov  9 22:39 file1
Nov  9 19:40 file2
Nov  9 19:39 file3
Nov  9 19:09 file4
```

then I get output like, which is neither ascending nor descending.

```
file2
file1
file3
file4
```

I have tried both st_mtime and st_ctime as I know that sometimes the creation date is not available. If I look at the output of "ls -lt" then I see all the files, with the correct time, sorted in the correct order - so I know the files contain the information I need.

```
int datesort(const struct dirent** file1, const struct dirent** file2) {
    struct stat info1, info2;
    stat((*file1)->d_name, &info1);
    stat((*file2)->d_name, &info2);

    double diff = difftime(info1.st_ctime, info2.st_ctime);
    if (diff<0) {return -1;}
    if (diff>0) {return 1;}
    if (diff==0) {return 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`d_name` is just the filename, not the filepath. So the `stat` will only succeed if you're examining the current working directory. Otherwise, you'll either `stat` some other file, which coincidentally has the same name as a file in the target directory, or `scan` will return an error.

Checking all system calls for error returns is a really good habit to get into. It can save many hours of debugging time.

Also, even if corrected, that code will end up calling `stat` multiple times on the same file, which is pretty inefficient (although modern OSs generally cache stat data, and even filepath resolution information, so it's not as awful as it used to be). You'd be better off using `readdir` to get an unsorted vector of dirents, then collecting the `stat` for each file once, and then sorting the file vector according to the stat vector. (Alternatively, you could keep a hash-map of creation time indexed by inode, but that's even more work.)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason adding the path still does not work (even though stat is returning 0); however, running chdir() then using scandir(".", ...) works. I'll keep the cache idea in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Found a working implementation

```
/* sortbydatetime - helper for scandir sorting */

static inline int
sortbydatetime(const struct dirent **a, const struct dirent **b)
{
    int rval;
    struct stat sbuf1, sbuf2;
    char path1[PATH_MAX], path2[PATH_MAX];

    snprintf(path1, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", PRINT_SPOOLER_PATH, (*a)->d_name);
    snprintf(path2, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", PRINT_SPOOLER_PATH, (*b)->d_name);

    rval = stat(path1, &sbuf1);
    if (rval) {
        perror("stat");
        return 0;
    }
    rval = stat(path2, &sbuf2);
    if (rval) {
        perror("stat");
        return 0;
    }

    return sbuf1.st_mtime < sbuf2.st_mtime;
}
```

This is part of SPOOL Queue code from

https://github.com/vatlidak/cucs-sea-hmwk2/blob/master/src/showqueue.c#L30

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is incorrect.

> return sbuf1.st_mtime < sbuf2.st_mtime;

it will return 0 if sbuf1.st_mtime > sbuf2.st_mtime, and return 0 will cause uncertain order

should be:

> return sbuf1.st_mtime - sbuf2.st_mtime;